# Foreign key as an array in like field

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
Table(
        "likes",
        metadata,
        Column("id", UUID, primary_key=True),
        Column(
            "post_id",
            ForeignKey(f"{_post_table}.id", ondelete="CASCADE"),
            nullable=False
        ),
       
        Column("likes",ARRAY(UUID)),
        Column("created_at", DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False),
        Column("updated_at", DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
    )
```

I want to define a relationship for my likes array, likes will be list of array but likes(UUID) in array will be only from user table , kindly tell me how to define this relationship. Here I need to define foreign key for array in likes.Without defining this relationship we will be able to add any number of random generated uuid in likes
Thanks

Comment: you can't define foreign keys on arrays. Use a properly normalized data model, then this is easy

Comment: Best solution is to normalize the data model as suggested by @a_horse_with _no_name. An other solution is to check a condition with trigger functions on insert and on update.